# Number of ancestors 750 years ago

Tags: arithmetic

I have 2 ancestors, a father and a mother.
Two generations back - 4 ancestors.
Three generations back - 8 ancestors.

30 generations back: 2^n = 2^30 = ~1,000,000,000 ancestors.

If a generation is 25 years long, 30 generations are 750 years and 30 generations ago the year was 1,267. But the world population was only 400,000,000 people so how can my math be wrong? and is there a way to estimate the number of ancestors I had 750 years ago?

Comment: What happens if a father and a mother has more than $1$ child?

Comment: Yes, the population grow exponentially but the number of ancestors also grow or evidently it doesn't especially if there is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_universal_common_ancestor.

Comment: @AsafKaragila How are siblings related? Every couple can have one child and still if all your ancestors were unique individuals you would have 2^n ancestors. and why mock the question?

Comment: I'm not mocking the question. It was a sarcastic remark about the sibling issue that was brought by others. The question, however, is still not a mathematical question, and has no business on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ancestors are not unique.  We don't need cousin marrying incest even.  In all likelihood your great great grand parents lived in a country or community where they had a choose of between a few thousand or even 100 of thousand choices but of any pair of the thousands there was a 90 percent chance that pair would have 90 percent common ancestors 15 generations back.  Eventually you'll have a base" stock" of several thousand *all* with same ancestors with a new influx every few generations.

Answer (score 1):

Your ancestors are not all unique individuals.  That is why your math shows one number when in fact the world had only much less people at the time.  Some of your ancestors had children with their cousins and I'm sure maybe even brothers or sisters.  It cannot be avoided with a finite population.

One could ask "how many unique ancestors did I have?" but such questions are just not answerable.

Comment: They're not answerable *precisely*.  It may still be instructive to make some reasonable assumptions about the population curve and interbreeding, and see what approximations and bounds one can come up with.

Comment: Not to mention even completely unrelated people will have multiple kids so give I have 2 parents so do my 4 siblings.  So on average we have .4, not 2 distinct parents.  That needs to be the base, not 2..

Comment: Oh, never mind.  I misread thw question.